# JQuery Simple Colour Picker Click Not Firing

Tags: jquery, plugins

I've downloaded the Really Simple Color Picker in jQuery from this [site](http://www.web2media.net/laktek/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/)

I've followed the instructions, an implemented the colorpicker like so:

**The HTML**

```
<input id="DashboardTreeHeaderFontColour" type="text" value="#333399"/>
```

**The Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () { $("#DashboardTreeHeaderFontColour").colorPicker() });
```

The small colour box is created, but clicking on it does nothing (it's suppoed to show the other colour options for you to choose from)

I'm using the latest Jquery.

Thanks for any help.

Regards,
Byron Cobb

Comment: Do you mean color picker does not show/open up? Also make sure that you have an element with id `DashboardTreeHeaderFontColour`

Comment: Could you post a small, _complete_ example that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, but i've found the solution and commented it on Andy's Answer Below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set up [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/GA67R/2/) using your exact code, importing the script and CSS files from the [demo page](http://www.web2media.net/samples/color_picker/demo.html).  It works fine in IE, Firefox and Chrome.  I would check the following:

- The swatch that appears needs to be properly styled, make sure you have declared CSS rules for it.  Just copy the rules from the demo page to begin with, then you can edit them to style it how you like.
- Make sure you don't have any conflicting CSS rules.  The id of the colour swatch that appears is *color_selector*.
- Check you're using the latest version of the file (released October 2009).
- Look in your web debugger (Firebug, IE dev tools, Chrome dev tools, etc) and try and find the element.
- Check your script console in the web debugger and see if you have any errors when clicking the input.

Comment: So running through ALL my code i've finally found the problem. I'm using Jquery layout and when applied the popup does not show. I set my z-index in the css and that finally did the trick.
Your answer set me on the right track, thanks.

Comment: @Byron: no problem, glad you got it sorted :-)